# What OS would be have best performance for an older computer?

Tags: linux, macintosh

I have a Mac Mini of unknown age. 
The specs are:

- OSX 10.6.8.
- 1.83 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
- 2 GB RAM 667 MHz DDR2 SDRAM.

I have a Snow Leopard OS Install Disk, but was considering installing Linux.

Is there a distribution available that would run reasonably well on this machine given it's outdated specification?

I intend to use it as a development machine. Standard LAMP stack.

Comment: This is going to get closed, sorry. But I suggest you experiment. Any modern distribution would probably work, but I'd first try Debian, whose base installation footprint is quite small. Just unselect everything optional at install time. If you run a light on resources desktop it will probably run Ok. But you don't say what you are planning to do with it. I doubt such a machine would be suitable for normal desktop use.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thanks for the recommendation. I certainly will experiment, but I am new to the world of linux, and was hoping those with experience could point me in the right direction. I intend to use it as a dev machine for LAMP stack development. I have added this to the OP.

Comment: If you want to ask about such things, you can do so in the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat).

Comment: So long as you're not using a heavy IDE such as Netbeans, Eclipse, etc. I'd have thought this would be fine for dev work... Use Vim - it'll be well worth the initial effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have current versions of Ubuntu (15.10) and Mint (17.3) running happily on an Intel Core 2 Duo E4400 @ 2GHz with 4Gb RAM

However, if you're worried that a full fat distribution might be a bit slow then [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/tags/light-ubuntu) might be worth a look.

> Lubuntu is a flavor of Ubuntu based on the Lightweight X11 Desktop
>   Environment (LXDE), as its default GUI. The goal is to provide a very
>   lightweight distribution, with all the advantages of the Ubuntu world
>   (repositories, support, etc.). Lubuntu is targeted at "normal" PC and
>   laptop users running on low-spec hardware.

Comment: I have Ubuntu Gnome on a slightly newer computer with 3 GB Ram and 2.3 GHz Dual Core. On there, it seems to bog down fairly quickly, especially when using more then one application. Do you think that might just be Gnome? Or are my fears that this will happen to the mac as well unfounded and thus the problem fixed by using Lubuntu as you recommended?

Comment: Core 2 Duo with 4Mb RAM? That's barely more than the CPU's cache...

Comment: Sorry yes. 4Gb will update the answer

Comment: Perhaps that is down to Gnome, although I don't think Unity is thought of as being particularly slim / fast... Install isn't much of a hassle.. why don't you give Ubuntu a go and if it seems slow try Lubuntu... What IDE are you using? Maybe that's what's slowing it down.

Comment: No IDE. Its a localhost web server and I code in Atom.

Comment: I'd of thought it should be ok. http://xubuntu.org/ is another alternative that you might take a look at.